# Variant - are old values' cleaned up when assigning a new value?

Tags: c++, c++17

Are previous variant's values cleaned up when a new value is assigned to the variant?

```
std::variant<std::string, std::vector<int>> v;
v = std::string("foo");
v = std::vector<int>(); // is string's destructor called above?
```

I'm assuming the previous values for containers are automatically freed when new values are set into the variant.

Comment: Yes https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/operator%3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the `string`s destructor is called before the `vector<int>` is copied in.